# Append data to data frame in a loop - function only returns last row of data frame

Tags: r

I want to create a function which loops through a large number of files, calculates the number of complete cases for each file and then appends a new row to an existing data frame with the "ID" number of the file and its corresponding number of complete cases.

Below I have created a code which only returns the last row of the data frame. I belive my function only returns the last row, because R overwrites my data frame in every loop, but I am not sure. I have done a lot of research online how to solve this, but I could not find an easy solution (I am very very new to R).

Below you can see my code and the output I get:

```
complete <- function(directory = "specdata", id = 1:332) {
  files_list <- list.files("specdata", full.names = T) # creates a list of files

  dat <- data.frame() # creates an emmpty data frame

    for (i in id) {

    data <- read.csv(files_list[i]) # reads the file "i" in the id vector 

    nobs <- sum(complete.cases(data)) # counts the number of complete cases in that file  

    data_frame <- data.frame("ID" = i, nobs) # here I want to store the number of complete cases in a data frame

    output <- rbind(dat, data_frame) # here the data_frame should be added to an existing data frame
  }

  print(output)
}
```

When I run `complete( , 3:5)`, I get the following result:

```
  ID nobs
1  5  402
```

Thanks four your help! :)

Comment: I would approach this differently: (1) write a function that calculates the number of complete cases in a single file, (2) use lapply() to apply that function to the list of files, and (3) use do.call() with rbind() to construct the final data frame. You could integrate all three steps in a single function at a later stage. It is a bit difficult to write the respective code without having a reproducible example, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 9):

As Maxim.K said, there are better ways to do this but the actual problem here is that your `output` variable gets overwritten at each iteration in the `for` loop.

Try :

```
dat <- rbind(dat, data_frame)
```

and print `dat`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `for (i in id) {`, try `for (i in 1:322) {` or `for (i in 1:length(id) {` at the beginning of your loop